# Unable to post to flask restful endpoint with Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-requests, flask-restful

I've an endpoint which accepts JSON

```
api.add_resource(EventsList, '/events')
```

The Flask Restful / SQL Alchemy is:

```
class EventsList (Resource):
    #RETURNS ALL EVENTS
    def get(self):
        schema = EventSchema()
        result = db.session.query(EventModel).all()
        return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200

    #POSTS A SINGLE EVENT
    def post(self):

        title = request.json['title']
        date = request.json['date']

        event = EventModel(title=title,date=date)

        db.session.add(event)
        db.session.commit()

        data = ({'title': event.title,
                 'date': event.date})

        response = jsonify(data)
        response.status_code = 200
        return response
```

When using curl via the command line this works absolutely fine:

### Curl Request

```
curl http://localhost:5002/events -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title": "TEst Event 3", "date":"2020-02-23"}'
```

### Curl Response

The response contains the data as expected:

```
{"date":"Sun, 23 Feb 2020 00:00:00 GMT","title":"TEst Event 3"}
```

This all works fine. However, when I attempt to do this from Python I receive a server error.

#### Python

```
import importlib
import subprocess
import csv
import sys
import requests

targetWikiPage = input("Target Wiki Page: ")
eventTitle = input("Event Title: ")
eventDate = input("Event Date: ")

    
#POST AN EVENT
data = '{"title": "'+eventTitle+'","date":"'+eventDate+'"}'
print("SENDING EVENT DATA:")
print(requests.body)
print(requests.headers)

response = requests.post("http://localhost:5002/events", json=data)
```

#### Server Console Output

```
[2020-09-28 16:38:14,182] ERROR in app: Exception on /events [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 468, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 89, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 583, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "api.py", line 155, in post
    title = request.json['title']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2020 16:38:14] "POST /events HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this.

The problem lay with how I was sending the data to the server. This is what I had:

```
targetWikiPage = input("Target Wiki Page: ")
eventTitle = input("Event Title: ")
eventDate = input("Event Date: ")

    
#POST AN EVENT
data = '{"title": "'+eventTitle+'","date":"'+eventDate+'"}'
print("SENDING EVENT DATA:")
print(requests.body)
print(requests.headers)

response = requests.post("http://localhost:5002/events", json=data)
```

Note that my `requests.post` had two values being passed. The url and the data.

The problems were as below:

1. The data was formatted incorrectly. This should have been:

`data = json.dumps({"title": eventTitle, "date": eventDate})`

2. I needed to add headers:

`headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}`

3. I needed to pass a `data` value to the server, not `json`

`requests.post("http://localhost:5002/events", headers=headers, data=data)`

That changed my file to this:

```
targetWikiPage = input("Target Wiki Page: ")
eventTitle = input("Event Title: ")
eventDate = input("Event Date: ")

#POST AN EVENT
data = json.dumps({"title": eventTitle, "date": eventDate})
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
print(data)
print(headers)
print("SENDING EVENT DATA:")

response = requests.post("http://localhost:5002/events", headers=headers, data=data)
json=json.loads(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have JSON data in a string object. Trying to extract a value from the string via its key will produce the error you described

```py
>>> response = '{"date":"Sun, 23 Feb 2020 00:00:00 GMT","title":"TEst Event 3"}'
>>> response_date = response["date"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    response_date = response["date"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

You need to convert the string to a `dict` first, then extract the value

```py
>>> import json
>>> response_as_json = json.loads(response)
>>> response_date = response_as_json["date"]
>>> response_date
'Sun, 23 Feb 2020 00:00:00 GMT'
```

Comment: The problem seems to originate is in the request received by the endpoint and parsed in the resource, rather than the response received by the client as you suggest.

Comment: Did you write the code in api.py? The stack trace shows that the error occurs at line 155 in that file.

Comment: Yep, line 155 is: `title = request.json['title']` in the `POST` above.

Comment: So you need to run the `request.json` string through `json.loads` before you try and extract  `['title']`